# Docker compose does not pick up changed docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that defines five different services. Four of them are dependent services and one is the application I am working on.

Typical development steps are:

1. Build my jar file
2. Create a docker image
3. Run "docker-compose up" command. This results in creating all the five running containers.

Each time I make a code change, I first need to kill my docker-compose process and go through the above listed steps. I feel this is not efficient as the dependent four services have not changed. There is no real need to stop the other four containers.

I tried doing the following:

1. Stop my application container (I generally do it from the docker desktop app)
2. Build docker image
3. Start the stopped container.

However, this doesn't seem to pick my new docker image.

How do I tell docker-compose to let go the current container and use the newly created image (without bringing down the other four running containers)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

U don't need to start/stop your containers, just use [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).
If in your docker compose file your application service is provide with *build* property use this:

```sh
docker compose up -d --build
```

otherwise u can add --force-recreate {service_name} to force creating process for specific service

Comment: Thank you. If I understand you right, I could simply run "docker-compose up" from one shell terminal. If I build a new image, I simply would run "docker-compose up --force-recreate myservice" from another terminal. Is this right?

Comment: If u want, u can run this command from another terminal but i suggest to look at -d option to run docker compose in detached mode so u can manage docker in one terminal. If u want to see logs from service check docker compose logs {service_name} -f. If it is possible I strongly recommend to add image build process to your compose and then run docker compose up --build so all your service image will be built automatically